# $\{(x,y) \mid 0<x<1,0<y<1\} \cong \mathbb{R^2}$?

Tags: general-topology

My proposed solution

Prove $A = \{(x,y) \mid 0<x<1,0<y<1\} \cong \mathbb{R^2}$??

$f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$.

$f(x)=x$.

$f$ is continuous and bijective. $f^{-1}$ is also continuous. Hence $\{(x,y) \mid 0<x<1,0<y<1\} \cong \mathbb{R^2}$?.

Comment: None of what you've written makes any sense

Comment: Please state what it is that your are trying to prove. Transcribing what you have written would also help.

Comment: You claim that $f$ is a bijection. Can you tell me which element maps to the origin of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 0):

In general $[0,1[$ can be mapped one-to-one to $\mathbb R$ via this usual construction
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
[0,1[ @>\phi>> ]0,1[ @>2x-1>> ]-1,1[ @>\mathrm{argth}>> \mathbb R
\end{CD}

With $\begin{cases}\phi(0)=\frac12,\phi(\frac12)=\frac14,\phi(\frac14)=\frac18,..,\phi(\frac1{2^n})=\frac1{2^{n+1}}\quad \mathrm{for}\ n\in\mathbb N \\
\phi(x)=x\quad \mathrm{elsewhere}\end{cases}$

---

In your case you already start from $]0,1[^2$ so you don't need $\phi$.

$f:A\mapsto\mathbb R^2,\ f(x,y)=(\tanh^{-1}(2x-1),\tanh^{-1}(2y-1))$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's obvious that 
$$
\{(x, y)\mid 0<x<1,0<y<1\}\cong \{(x, y)\mid -0.5<x<0.5,-0.5<y<0.5\}
$$
by moving the area to be centered at $(0, 0)$

Second, consider the function $f(x, y):\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \{(x, y)\mid -0.5<x<0.5,-0.5<y<0.5\}$
$$
f(x, y)=(\dfrac{x}{2(1+\mid x \mid)}, \dfrac{y}{2(1+\mid y \mid)})
$$
And you can verify it's a continuous bijection.

Comment: it should be $\frac x{1-2|x|}$

Comment: yeah, but I defined f(x, y) from R^2 to the area, which is more intuitive to me, although it should be from the area to R^2.